# How to play pcm through I2S?

Tags: pcm, arduino-esp32, i2s

I have ESP32-WROOM-32D board and MAX98357A I2S board which i need to play 8Khz 8bit PCM audio. The pcm audio buffer is declared  as a constant buffer in header wavedata.h like below

```
const uint8_t rawData[49428] = {0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46,.......};
```

Below is my test code for playing this buffer audio through I2S

```
#include "wavedata.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <I2S.h>

#define LRC_PIN             26
#define BCLK_PIN            27
#define DOUT_PIN            25
void setup()
{
    I2S.begin(I2S_PHILIPS_MODE, 8000, 8);
    I2S.setSckPin(BCLK_PIN);
    I2S.setFsPin(LRC_PIN);
    I2S.setDataPin(DOUT_PIN);
    
}
void loop()
{
    I2S.write_blocking(rawData,49428);
    delay(1000);
}
```

But I am not hearing any sound from the speaker.

I tried like below also

```
#include "driver/i2s.h"
#include "wavedata.h"

#define I2S_SAMPLE_RATE     (8000)
#define I2S_SAMPLE_BITS     (I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_8BIT)
#define I2S_CHANNEL_NUM     (1)
#define I2S_BUFFER_SIZE     (512)
#define PIN_LRC             25
#define PIN_BCLK            14
#define PIN_DIN             I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE
#define PIN_DOUT            25
#define MCK                 I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE

void setup()
{
    
    i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
        .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER),
        .sample_rate = I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,
        .bits_per_sample = I2S_SAMPLE_BITS,
        .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ALL_LEFT,
        .communication_format = (i2s_comm_format_t)(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S),
        .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
        .dma_buf_count = 16,
        .dma_buf_len = I2S_BUFFER_SIZE,
        .use_apll = false,          // must be disabled in V2.0.1-RC1
        .tx_desc_auto_clear = true, // new in V1.0.1
        .fixed_mclk = I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE,
    };
    i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
        .bck_io_num = PIN_BCLK,
        .ws_io_num = PIN_LRC,
        .data_out_num = PIN_DOUT,
        .data_in_num = PIN_DIN,
    };

    i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
    i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pin_config);
    i2s_set_sample_rates(I2S_NUM_0, I2S_SAMPLE_RATE);

    size_t written_bytes = 0;
    while (written_bytes < sizeof(rawData)) {
        size_t bytes_to_write = sizeof(rawData) - written_bytes;
        if (bytes_to_write > I2S_BUFFER_SIZE) {
            bytes_to_write = I2S_BUFFER_SIZE;
        }
        i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, &rawData[written_bytes], bytes_to_write, &written_bytes, portMAX_DELAY);
    }

    i2s_driver_uninstall(I2S_NUM_0);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Above code also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the working code below. One point I noted is for MAX98357A at-least 16 bit audio is required to play pcm

```
#include "driver/i2s.h"
#include "wavedata16.h"

#define I2S_SAMPLE_RATE     (8000)
#define I2S_SAMPLE_BITS     (I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT)
#define I2S_CHANNEL_NUM     (1)
#define I2S_BUFFER_SIZE     (16)
#define PIN_LRC             12
#define PIN_BCLK            14
#define PIN_DIN             I2S_PIN_NO_CHANGE
#define PIN_DOUT            26

void setup()
{
    
    i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
        .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER| I2S_MODE_TX),
        .sample_rate = I2S_SAMPLE_RATE,
        .bits_per_sample = I2S_SAMPLE_BITS,
        .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ALL_RIGHT,
        .communication_format = (i2s_comm_format_t)(I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_I2S | I2S_COMM_FORMAT_STAND_MSB),
        .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
        .dma_buf_count = 16,
        .dma_buf_len = I2S_BUFFER_SIZE,
    };
    i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
        .bck_io_num = PIN_BCLK,
        .ws_io_num = PIN_LRC,
        .data_out_num = PIN_DOUT,
        .data_in_num = PIN_DIN,
    };

    i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
    i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pin_config);
    i2s_set_clk((i2s_port_t)0, I2S_SAMPLE_RATE, I2S_SAMPLE_BITS, (i2s_channel_t)1);

}
size_t written_bytes = 0;
void loop()
{
  if (written_bytes >= ARRAY_LEN)
    written_bytes = 0;
  size_t bytes_to_write = sizeof(rawData) - written_bytes;
  i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, &rawData[written_bytes], bytes_to_write, &written_bytes, portMAX_DELAY);
}
```

Another method is using I2S library see below code

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <I2S.h>
#include "wavedata16.h"
#define I2S_SAMPLE_RATE     8000
#define I2S_SAMPLE_BITS     16

#define PIN_LRC             12
#define PIN_BCLK            14
#define PIN_DOUT            26
int count = 0;

void setup() {


I2S.setSckPin(PIN_BCLK);
I2S.setFsPin(PIN_LRC);
  if (!I2S.begin(I2S_PHILIPS_MODE, I2S_SAMPLE_RATE, I2S_SAMPLE_BITS)) {

    Serial.println("Failed to initialize I2S!");

    while (1); // do nothing

  }
}

void loop() {

if(count>=ARRAY_LEN)
   count=0;
I2S.write(rawData[count]);
I2S.write(rawData[count]);
count++;

}
```

But if you want to play 8 bit PCM buffer a little tricky way is there see below code

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <I2S.h>
#include "wavedata.h"
#define I2S_SAMPLE_RATE     8000
#define I2S_SAMPLE_BITS     16

#define PIN_LRC             12
#define PIN_BCLK            14
#define PIN_DOUT            33
int count = 0;

void setup() {


I2S.setSckPin(PIN_BCLK);
I2S.setFsPin(PIN_LRC);
I2S.setDataPin(PIN_DOUT);
  if (!I2S.begin(I2S_PHILIPS_MODE, I2S_SAMPLE_RATE, I2S_SAMPLE_BITS)) {

    Serial.println("Failed to initialize I2S!");

    while (1); // do nothing

  }
}

void loop() {

if(count>=ARRAY_LEN)
   count=0;
int16_t res = map(rawData[count],0,255,-32768,32767);
I2S.write(res);
I2S.write(res);
count++;

}
```

Comment: If you are answering your own question, you should click on the tick to accept it as an answer for the benefit of future readers.